# How can i get all the approval process names for a specific object in salesforce

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

i have to write a query to get all the approval processes on a specific xyz__c custom object

select Name from ProcessDefinition

the above query display all objects approval processes .but i need specific approval process on a particular object

Answer (score 2):

The [`TableEnumOrId`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_processdefinition.htm#!) field is the one you need to query:

> Specifies the object associated with the approval process, such as Account or Contact.

Hence

```
SELECT Id, TableEnumOrId FROM ProcessDefinition
```